# Cypress - is it possible to store repeated parts of tests in one place?

Tags: cypress

I have many test cases for the same application views. These views display different data depending on the response from the server. I have 18 test cases in which I check 6 almost identical views. I noticed that a lot of tests are repeating to me.

I have a question, can you store any references to avoid duplicate code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, yes you can.

Cypress commands can be queued from an external function, so long as that function is called from somewhere inside an `it()` block. You can create a separate function that takes arguments to help it distinguish between your different views.

Here's a simple example:

```js
function myExternalFunction(info) {
    cy.log(info);
    // ...
}

describe('My test', function() {
    it('Calls another function to queue test commands', function() {
        myExternalFunction("test");
    }
}
```